# List<Enum> fails to deserialize when no values are provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

In a class Account, The property Industry is a collection of Enum type Industry

An account can belong to multiple industry's.

```
public class Account
{

[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public List<Industry> Industrys { get; set; } 

}

Public enum Industry
{
AerospaceAirlines = 0,
            Agriculture = 1,
            Apparel = 2,
            Automotive = 3,
            Banking = 4,
            BioTechnology = 5,
            Chemicals = 6,
            Communications = 7,
            Construction = 8,
            Consultancy = 9,
            ConsumerDurables = 10,
            Education = 11,
}
```

when a new account is created, It is not mandatory to add industry. when no values are provided in the request object for this Industrys property fails.

there is an error comes from De-serializing "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"

The failure happens when the default binder tries to populate accountModel object.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]AccountModel accountModel)
        {
            if (accountModel == null)
            {
                throw new ApiException(ApplicationErrorCode.FieldRequiredError, "request cannot be empty");
            }
       }
```

How can I allow the sender to send the request without Industry supplied?

Comment: I confess I would have had 0 as "undefined" and have it default to 0..

Comment: @BugFinder he has a list of enums.  I think you are thinking of an enum that is a set of Flags.

Comment: Most serialisation (has to) store the class in the Collection Elements. So without a Element in the list, there is lierally no way for the deserializer to figure out what to use here.

Comment: Industries not industry's ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
public class Account
{

[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public List<Industry> Industrys { get; set; } 

}
```

to:

```
public class Account
{

[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public List<Industry> Industrys { get; set; } = new List<Industry>();

}
```